# Multi-dimensional arrays php to table rowspan

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I'm stuck at these.

```
this is my array:
$tabel3 = array (

array (
"progdas" => "Java", "sks" => "3", "prior" => "2"
),
array (
"progdas" => "C#", "sks" => "6", "prior" => "1"
),
array (
"mat" =>  "Dasar", "sks" => "3", "prior" => "1"
),
array (
"mat" =>  "Lanjut", "sks" => "3", "prior" => "3"
),

);
```

and this is the code for showing it at tables :

```
<?php
echo "Tabel 3<br />";


echo "<table width='auto' border='1'>";
    //header
    echo "
    <table width='auto' border='1'  >
    <tr>
      <th colspan='2' scope='col'>Mata Kuliah</th>
      <th width='auto' scope='col'>Jumlah SKS</th>
      <th width='auto' scope='col'>Prioritas</th>
    </tr>
    ";


foreach ($tabel3 as $rows => $row)
{   
    //isi   
        echo "<tr>";

    if ($cell == "progdas") {
        echo "<th width='auto' rowspan='2' scope='row'>Pemrograman Dasar</th>";
        foreach ($row as $col => $cell)
    {

        echo "<td>" . $cell. "</td>";       
    }
        }

        else {
            echo "<th width='auto' rowspan='2' scope='row'>Matematika</th>";
    foreach ($row as $col => $cell)
    {

        echo "<td>" . $cell. "</td>";       
    }       
            }


    echo "</tr>";
}   


echo "</table>";        
?>
```

I want the tables are looked like this :

```
----------------------------------------------------- 
Mata Kuliah               | Jumlah SKS | Prioritas  |
----------------------------------------------------- 
Pemrograman Dasar|_Java___|____________|____________|
_________________|_C#_____|____________|____________| 
Matematika       |_Dasar__|____________|____________|
_________________|_Lanjut_|____________|____________|
```

Does someone know how to rowspan data "Pemrograman Dasar " and "Matematika"? I get the bad result at this code.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to rebuild your array

```
foreach ($tabel3 as $row) {
    $row_keys = array_keys($row);
    $rebuilded[$row_keys[0]][] = $row; 
}
```

After this you can get next array:

```
Array ( 
    [progdas] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [progdas] => Java [sks] => 3 [prior] => 2 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [progdas] => C# [sks] => 6 [prior] => 1 ) 
    ) 
    [mat] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [mat] => Dasar [sks] => 3 [prior] => 1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [mat] => Lanjut [sks] => 3 [prior] => 3 ) 
)
```

)

After this reorganization you can construct html code

```
<?php
echo "Tabel 3<br />";


echo "<table width='auto' border='1'>";
echo "
<table width='auto' border='1'  >
<tr>
  <th colspan='2' scope='col'>Mata Kuliah</th>
  <th width='auto' scope='col'>Jumlah SKS</th>
  <th width='auto' scope='col'>Prioritas</th>
</tr>
";


foreach ($rebuilded as $key => $group)
{

echo "<tr><th width='auto' rowspan='".count($group)."' scope='row'>".($key == "progdas" ? "Pemrograman Dasar" : "Matematika")."</th>";
foreach ($group as $row)
{
    echo "<td>" . ($key == "progdas" ? $row['progdas'] : $row['mat']). "</td><td>" . $row['sks']. "</td><td>" . $row['prior']. "</td></tr>";       
}
```

}

```
echo "</table>";
```

?>